# Is there a way to limit number of images or pages in owl carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I am trying to display only 3 pages where each slide contains 4 items(images)  to display content with images using owl carousel. Limiting the total number of images to 12( I have 30-40 images in the folder path) or limit the number of pages. The images are stored in a particular folder path and not defined in the HTML file.

To limit the number of images in each page I have used this.I want to limit the number of pages displayed to 3(with 4 images in each) or total number of images to 12.

```
$("#owl-example").owlCarousel(
{
    items:4,
    navigation: true
});
```

Comment: what you did wrote is exactly what you want , you did answer your own question. i really don't understand what you want :p :p

Comment: here is your solution : https://jsfiddle.net/roonie007/8f0oy48n/

Comment: I want to control the number of slides  as in there are 4 items(images) in each slides...and i want to limit the number of slides to 3 ..i.e total of 12 images are displayed in 3 slides(pages) with 4 images(items) in each slides.

Comment: yes that's what is in the demo https://jsfiddle.net/roonie007/8f0oy48n/

Comment: Can you update the number of slides to two..there are 3 slides over there?What i am trying to say it I want to limit the number of images and use only two slide..In your example I want only two slides with 8 images. with 4 images in each

Comment: but you said "I am trying to display only 3 of the slides (or pages) where each slide contains 4 items to display"

Comment: yes but I had like 20 items...the isssue here is to limit the page as we limit the item..i want to check if there is a way for that...Its similar to your example ..in your example i want to display only 8 images may be...with 2 images in each slide(page)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/roonie007/8f0oy48n/2/ check this

Comment: Thanks your solution is good for the images defined in HTML file I am pulling the images from a folder path using .xsl:value-of select="./path/image" from the images stored in folder so was wondering if there is something inherent in owl carousel to limit number of images or number of pages..Never the logic seems good ..I was thinking about the similar way but not for this particular case i guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I solved the problem was by limiting the number of slides as done previously using

```js
$("#owl-example").owlCarousel(
{
    items:4,
    navigation: true
});
```

I looked for the ways  to limit the number of pages in owl carousel but the only way i figured was to limit the number of images before displaying item using owl carousel and since I was using XSLT to displayin the images by applying the templates I figured limiting Items(images) while template was being applied. Would love to see if anybody has better way to limit images or pages in owl carousel itself.